# How to obtain the operator in time domain using multi-mode Hamiltonian of the optical cavity system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, hamiltonian

I'm trying to get the average photon number of each mode in the optical cavity system with the hamiltonians:

- $\hat H_{Free\ optical\ wave} = \hbar w \hat a_i^† \hat a_i$
- $\hat H_{Free\ cavity} = \hbar w_c \hat a^† \hat a$
- $\hat H_{Interaction} = -i\hbar \sqrt \kappa_c \int_{-∞}^{∞} dw [\hat a^† \hat a_i(w) - \hat a_i^†(w) \hat a]$
- $\hat H_{Dissipation\ of\ cavity} = \frac{-i\hbar \kappa}{2} \hat a^† \hat a$

where $\hat a,\hat a_i,\hat a_o$ are cavity mode, input mode, reflected output mode, respectively. There is a boundary condition of the cavity, $\hat a_o(t)= \hat a_i(t) + \sqrt \kappa_c\hat a(t)$ or $\hat a_o(w)= \hat a_i(w) + \sqrt \kappa_c\hat a(w)$ by Fourier transform, which is obtained by input-output theorem of the cavity via Heisenber equation.

[image]

Using the Heisenberg equation, I can get two differential equations:

$\frac{d\hat a(t)}{dt} = \frac{-i}{\hbar} [\hat a(t),\hat H_{total}]$

$\frac{d\hat a_i(w)}{dt'} = \frac{-i}{\hbar} [\hat a_i(w),\hat H_{total}]$

By coupling these two equations above, I get

$\frac{d\hat a(t)}{dt} = \hat a(t)[-iw_c-\frac{\kappa+\kappa_c}{2}]-\sqrt \kappa_c \hat a_i(t)$

By solving this equation, I can obtain the following result:

$\hat a(t) = \hat a(0)*e^{-(iw_c + \frac{\kappa+\kappa_c}{2})t}- 
\sqrt \kappa_c \int_{0}^{t} dt' \hat a_i(t')*e^{(iw_c + \frac{\kappa+\kappa_c}{2})(t'-t)}$

Now, my problem is I can't get the mode operators in the time domain:

$\hat a(t), \hat a_i(t), \hat a_o(t)$

I tried to get each operator using $\hat a_i(t)= e^{i\hat H_{total} t/\hbar}\hat a_i(0)e^{-i\hat H_{total} t/\hbar}$ with giving some initial condition, $\hat a_i(0)|α>=α|α>$ where $|α>$ is a coherent state in the input field, but the result is infinity.

I guess it's because the $\hat H_{Interaction}$ is in the frequency domain so that it is also in the time domain by Fourier-transform and it doesn't fit to the above equation, $\hat a_i(t)= e^{i\hat H_{total} t/\hbar}\hat a_i(0)e^{-i\hat H_{total} t/\hbar}$ that requires time-independent $\hat H_{total}$.

Would you please let me know how to obtain $\hat a(t), \hat a_i(t), \hat a_o(t)$?

My last goal is to get the average photon number in each mode by setting the initial state condition in each mode with each corresponding mode operator.

Please help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: I think I don't understand something. What exactly is $a_i(\omega)$? is $\omega$ here the frequency (energy) of the free mode? What is being integrated over?

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly there are infinite modes of free light, and $H_{free} = \int\! d\omega \hbar \omega a^{\dagger}_i(\omega)a_i(\omega)$? Is there a density or frequency cutoff here?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think I can help you then. For me, something like $-i \int\! d\omega [a^{\dagger}a_i(\omega)-a^{\dagger}_i(\omega)a]$ implies that there are many different modes $a_i$ each with its own frequency $\omega$. I don't know how to interpret it otherwise.

Comment: Ok so in that case I think that you shouldn't interpretat $\int\! d\omega a_i(\omega)e^{i\omega t}$ as a Fourier transform to time-domain. This is just a basis change to another set of operators, but they exist at all times. I would suggest you stay with $a_i(\omega)$. I also come back to my previous question - is there some cutoff energy/frequency? if not, infinities can certainly arise as you have an infinite band.

Comment: Yes. Usually, to avoid infinities, one introduces some cutoff $D$ to the band. Be it by a step function or a Gaussian or Lorentzian density-of-states.

Comment: There are still things I don't understand (what is the boundary constraint, for example, or how do you incorporate the non-hermitian decay - do you use Lindblad equation?) , and I don't think that SE is the best way to tackle this. *However* you can try to solve the eom for $a$ and $a_i(\omega)$ which would involve integrals over all other $\omega '$. This set of equations could in principle be solved (at least for the no-dissipation case)